# Sanskrit translation of Mahabharata Adi Parva, Section CCXXXIV

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request

I'd like to know the praise of Agni Deva of below translation from Mahabharata, Adi Parva, Section CCXXXIV:

> Jaritari said, 'Thou art, O fire, the soul of air! Thou art the body of the Earth's vegetation! O Sukra, water is thy parent as thou art the parent of water! O thou of great energy, thy flames, like the rays of the sun, extend
> themselves above, below, behind, and on each side.'

> "Sarisrikka said, 'O smoke-bannered god, our mother is not to be seen, and we know not our father! Our feathers have not grown as yet. We have none to protect us save thee. Therefore, O Agni, infants that we are protect us! O Agni, as we are distressed, protect us with that auspicious form thou hast and with those seven flames of thine! We seek protection at thy hands. Thou alone, O Agni, art the giver of heat (in the universe). O lord, there is none else (save thee) that giveth heat to the rays of the sun. O, protect us who are young and who are Rishis. O Havyavaha (carrier of sacrificial butter), be pleased to go hence by some other route.'

> "Stamvamitra said, 'Thou alone, O Agni, art everything! This whole universe is established in thee! Thou sustainest every creature, and thou supportest the universe! Thou art the carrier of the sacrificial butter, and thou art the excellent sacrificial butter itself! The wise know thee to be one (as cause) and many (as effects)! Having created the three worlds, thou, O Havyavaha, again destroyest them when the time cometh, swelling thyself forth! Thou art the productive cause of the whole universe, and thou also art the essence in which the universe dissolveth itself!'

> "Drona said, 'O lord of the universe, growing in strength and remaining within their bodies, thou causest the food that living creatures eat to be digested. Everything therefore, is established in thee. O Sukra, O thou from whose mouth the Vedas have sprung, it is thou who assumests the form of the sun, and sucking up the waters of the earth and every liquid juice that the earth yields, givest them back in time in the form of rain and causest everything to grow! From thee, O Sukra, are these plants and creepers with green foliage! From thee have sprung these tanks and pools, and the great ocean also that is ever blessed! O thou of fierce rays, this our body dependeth on Varuna! We are unable to bear thy heat. Be thou, therefore, our auspicious protector! O, destroy us not! O thou of copper-hued eyes, O thou of red neck, O thou whose path is marked by a black colour, save us by going along any remote route, as indeed, the ocean saveth the house on its banks!'

I heard to know about this praise in Sanskrit.

Comment: If it's Sanskrit verses, three it's there in sacred texts website; see Sanskrit version of Mahabharata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chapter number and the shlokas of Mahabharata is slightly different for different editions. I'll answer  Sanskrit shlokas respectively from **Adi Parva** of

1. [Gita Press Gorakhpur edition](https://archive.org/download/unabridged-mahabharata-6-volumes-set-in-hindi-by-veda-vyasa-compressed/Mahabharata%20Volume%201.pdf), Chapter 231
2. [BORI critical edition](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh01_sa.html), Chapter 223
3. [Southern Khumbhakonam edition](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-01-sa.html), Chapter 258
4. Translation: [The Mahabharata translated by Kisari Mohan Ganguli](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01235.htm), SECTION CCXXXIV

---

1. 

[image]

2.

> जरितारिरुवाच||
>
> आत्मासि वायोः पवनः शरीरमुत वीरुधाम् |
> योनिरापश्च ते शुक्र योनिस्त्वमसि चाम्भसः ||७||
>
> ऊर्ध्वं चाधश्च गच्छन्ति विसर्पन्ति च पार्श्वतः |
> अर्चिषस्ते महावीर्य रश्मयः सवितुर्यथा ||८||

3. 

> जरितारिरुवाच।
>
> आत्माऽसि वायोर्ज्वलन शरीरमसि वीरुधाम्।
> योनिरापश्च ते शुक्रं योनिस्त्वमसि चाम्भसः॥ 1-258-7
>
> ऊर्ध्वं चाधश्च सर्पन्ति पृष्ठतः पार्श्वतस्तथा।
> अर्चिषस्ते महावीर्य रश्यमः सवितुर्यथा॥ 1-258-8

4. Translation:

> Jaritari said, 'Thou art, O fire, the soul of air! Thou art the body
> of the Earth's vegetation! O Sukra, water is thy parent as thou art
> the parent of water! O thou of great energy, thy flames, like the rays
> of the sun, extend themselves above, below, behind, and on each side.'

---

1. 

[image]

2.

> सारिसृक्व उवाच||
>
> माता प्रपन्ना पितरं न विद्मः; पक्षाश्च नो न प्रजाताब्जकेतो |
> न नस्त्राता विद्यतेऽग्ने त्वदन्य; स्तस्माद्धि नः परिरक्षैकवीर ||९||
>
> यदग्ने ते शिवं रूपं ये च ते सप्त हेतयः |
> तेन नः परिरक्षाद्य ईडितः शरणैषिणः ||१०||
>
> त्वमेवैकस्तपसे जातवेदो; नान्यस्तप्ता विद्यते गोषु देव |
> ऋषीनस्मान्बालकान्पालयस्व; परेणास्मान्प्रैहि वै हव्यवाह ||११||

3. 

> सारिसृक्क उवाच।
>
> माता प्रणष्टा पितरं न विद्मः
> पक्षा जाता नै नो धूमकेतो।
> न नस्त्राता विद्यते वै त्वदन्य-
> स्तस्मादस्मांस्त्राहि बालांस्त्वमग्ने॥ 1-258-9
>
> यदग्ने ते शिवं रूपं ये च ते सप्त हेतयः।
> तेन नः परिपाहि त्वमार्तान्नः शरणैषिणः॥ 1-258-10
>
> त्वमेवैकस्तपसे जप्तवेदो
> नान्यस्तप्ता विद्यते गोषु देव।
> ऋषीनस्मान्बालकान्पालयस्व
> परेणास्मान्प्रेहि वै हव्यवाह॥ 1-258-11

4. Translation:

> "Sarisrikka said, 'O smoke-bannered god, our mother is not to be seen,
> and we know not our father! Our feathers have not grown as yet. We
> have none to protect us save thee. Therefore, O Agni, infants that we
> are protect us! O Agni, as we are distressed, protect us with that
> auspicious form thou hast and with those seven flames of thine! We
> seek protection at thy hands. Thou alone, O Agni, art the giver of
> heat (in the universe). O lord, there is none else (save thee) that
> giveth heat to the rays of the sun. O, protect us who are young and
> who are Rishis. O Havyavaha (carrier of sacrificial butter), be
> pleased to go hence by some other route.'

---

1. 

[image]

2.

> स्तम्बमित्र उवाच||
>
> सर्वमग्ने त्वमेवैकस्त्वयि सर्वमिदं जगत् |
> त्वं धारयसि भूतानि भुवनं त्वं बिभर्षि च ||१२||
>
> त्वमग्निर्हव्यवाहस्त्वं त्वमेव परमं हविः |
> मनीषिणस्त्वां यजन्ते बहुधा चैकधैव च ||१३||
>
> सृष्ट्वा लोकांस्त्रीनिमान्हव्यवाह; प्राप्ते काले पचसि पुनः समिद्धः |
> सर्वस्यास्य भुवनस्य प्रसूति; स्त्वमेवाग्ने भवसि पुनः प्रतिष्ठा ||१४||
>
> त्वमन्नं प्राणिनां भुक्तमन्तर्भूतो जगत्पते |
> नित्यं प्रवृद्धः पचसि त्वयि सर्वं प्रतिष्ठितम् ||१५||

3. 

> स्तम्बमित्र उवाच।
>
> सर्वमग्ने त्वमेवैकस्त्वयि सर्वमिदं जगत्।
> त्वं धारयसि भूतानि भुवनं त्वं बिभर्षि च॥ 1-258-12
>
> त्वमग्निर्हव्यवाहस्त्वं त्वमेव परमं हविः।
> मनीषिणस्त्वां जानन्ति बहुधा चैकधापि च॥ 1-258-13
>
> सृष्ट्वा लोकांस्त्रीनिमान्हव्यवाह
> काले प्राप्ते पचसि पुनः समिद्धः।
> त्वं सर्वस्य भुवनस्य प्रसूति-
> स्त्वमेवाग्ने भवसि पुनः प्रतिष्ठा॥ 1-258-14

4. Translation:

> "Stamvamitra said, 'Thou alone, O Agni, art everything! This whole
> universe is established in thee! Thou sustainest every creature, and
> thou supportest the universe! Thou art the carrier of the sacrificial
> butter, and thou art the excellent sacrificial butter itself! The wise
> know thee to be one (as cause) and many (as effects)! Having created
> the three worlds, thou, O Havyavaha, again destroyest them when the
> time cometh, swelling thyself forth! Thou art the productive cause of
> the whole universe, and thou also art the essence in which the
> universe dissolveth itself!'

---

1. 

[image]

2. 

> द्रोण उवाच||
>
> सूर्यो भूत्वा रश्मिभिर्जातवेदो; भूमेरम्भो भूमिजातान्रसांश्च |
> विश्वानादाय पुनरुत्सर्गकाले; सृष्ट्वा वृष्ट्या भावयसीह शुक्र ||१६||
>
> त्वत्त एताः पुनः शुक्र वीरुधो हरितच्छदाः |
> जायन्ते पुष्करिण्यश्च समुद्रश्च महोदधिः ||१७||
>
> इदं वै सद्म तिग्मांशो वरुणस्य परायणम् |
> शिवस्त्राता भवास्माकं मास्मानद्य विनाशय ||१८||
>
> पिङ्गाक्ष लोहितग्रीव कृष्णवर्त्मन्हुताशन |
> परेण प्रैहि मुञ्चास्मान्सागरस्य गृहानिव ||१९||

3. 

> द्रोण उवाच।
>
> त्वमन्नं प्राणिभिर्भुक्तमन्तर्भूतो जगत्पते।
> नित्यप्रवृद्धः पचसि त्वयि सर्वं प्रतिष्ठितम्॥ 1-258-15
>
> सूर्यो भूत्वा रश्मिभिर्जातवेदो
> भूमेरम्भो भूमिजातान्रसांश्च।
> विश्वानादाय पुनरुत्सृज्य काले
> दृष्ट्वा वृष्ट्या भावयसीह शुक्र॥ 1-258-16
>
> त्वत्त एताः पुनः शुक्र वीरुधो हरितच्छदाः।
> जायन्ते पुष्करिण्यश्च सुभद्रश्च महोदधिः॥ 1-258-17
>
> इदं वै सद्म तिग्मांशो वरुणस्य परायणम्।
> शिवस्त्राता भवास्माकं माऽस्मानद्य विनाशय॥ 1-258-18
>
> पिङ्गाक्ष लोहितग्रीव कृष्णवर्त्मन्हुताशन।
> परेण प्रेहि मुञ्चास्मान्सागरस्य गृहानिव॥ 1-258-19

4. Translation:

> "Drona said, 'O lord of the universe, growing in strength and
> remaining within their bodies, thou causest the food that living
> creatures eat to be digested. Everything therefore, is established in
> thee. O Sukra, O thou from whose mouth the Vedas have sprung, it is
> thou who assumests the form of the sun, and sucking up the waters of
> the earth and every liquid juice that the earth yields, givest them
> back in time in the form of rain and causest everything to grow! From
> thee, O Sukra, are these plants and creepers with green foliage! From
> thee have sprung these tanks and pools, and the great ocean also that
> is ever blessed! O thou of fierce rays, this our body dependeth on
> Varuna! We are unable to bear thy heat. Be thou, therefore, our
> auspicious protector! O, destroy us not! O thou of copper-hued eyes, O
> thou of red neck, O thou whose path is marked by a black colour, save
> us by going along any remote route, as indeed, the ocean saveth the
> house on its banks!'